# asp.net response to urls exceeding max request

Tags: asp.net, security

I had set in my web.config a custom value for my maxUrlLength, thus the effect of putting a very long Url would be caught as an error. Given this situation, for example a hacker puts in an attack query in the url exceeding my maxUrlLength, it is given that this would result to an error, but I'd like to ask will the query be still executed on the server side? or since it is caught as error it has no effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`MaxUrlLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxurllength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will cause the web server to return the `HTTP 400 (Bad Request)` status code and will not process the request server side.

So it'll have no effect apart from causing the request to be recorded in any active logs.